# How to use jquery to add numbers to input ID name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, sequence

I am using a wordpress plugin that is generating a input field with a given ID name - `fieldname15_6`

Im using the code in a loop though so for each post it is creating that input field with the same ID name. Of course this is a problem. I have about 10 inputs with the same ID name and I believe it's causing issues with the display. The font sizes and spacing seems a little random regardless of my CSS rules.

Any how, I need a way to automatically add numbers 1+ to any of the created inputs with that ID name. I tried using the following code but it does nothing --

```
$("input[id^='fieldname15_6']").attr('id', function (i) {
    return "fieldname15_6" + ++i;
});
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: **I have about 10 inputs with the same ID name** ID should be unique

Comment: Ha, should be good luck with the old should be and html. :P

Comment: Is your code generating the input fields? If so, you should fix the unique ID issue at the time you generate them. The answers at present show how to fix the issue after the fields are created. Are you looking for code how to fix the generating fields?

Comment: if you are using jquery version >= 1.6, you can use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @guradio I am aware of that. I do not have control over it, it is created by the plugin.

Comment: @mygm26 what plugin are you using, the answer you have selected may fix your problem, but it is **not** the right way to do this. THe right way would be to actually address the issue of the plugin creating invalid `HTML` in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = 1;
$("input#fieldname15_6").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id', function(i) {
        return "fieldname15_6" + ++i;
    });
});
```

This will help you.....

Comment: This works, but it's akin to breaking a faucet at home and drilling a hole in your floor to drain the water rather than fixing the faucet....

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $files = $('body').find("input").attr("id","fieldname15_6");
$files.each(function(index) 
{
     newIndex = $(this).attr("id") + index;
     $(this).attr("class", newIndex );
});
```

Comment: `$(this) + i` will return an object rather than attribute

Comment: `$(this) + index`. What will it return?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity tnx. fixed.

Comment: @Mr.Wolf it returns `id="[object Object]2"`

Comment: this made my input fields stop appearing completely

Comment: @mygm26 You can add new class to them.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[id^='fieldname15_6']").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is **Don't**. You should use classes for this type of thing, that's what they are for. Then you can use various methods to target and work with the individual elements like [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$('#result').html($('.fieldname15_6').eq(2).val()); // eq is 0 based array syntax so 2 will be the 3rd element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="fieldname15_6" value="first value">
<input type="text" class="fieldname15_6" value="second value">
<input type="text" class="fieldname15_6" value="third value">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I dont have control over the plugin input attributes.

Comment: @mygm26 they have classnames right?you can use that and get the index  as suggested in this answer i think this is the best answer.

Comment: @mygm26 What plugin are you using, a well written plugin should not generate multiple inputs with the same `id` as this would be invalid `HTML`. I bet there is a way to change the output. But as guradion mentioned, if they all share some class now, you can still apply this. You shold really avoid incremental ids if possible....it can get messy with them